# Why is Ubuntu 19.10 so slow on Raspberry Pi 3B+

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, performance

I had recently installed Ubuntu 19.10 on my Raspberry Pi 3B+ believing it would provide wonderful performance. When I boot it up and then log in, I experience extremely sluggish performance. It takes about a minute to open and close an application, and if you were wondering, I have a Class 10 128 GB Micro SD Card. I was also running Raspbian before switching to Ubuntu and it wasn't sluggish or unusable. So I can infer the problem isn't probably with my Raspberry Pi. Can anyone help with this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The likely problem is that the embedded GPU on the Raspberry Pi isn't supported by any of the drivers in Ubuntu.  The unfortunate problem with embedded GPUs on many ARM systems, like the Raspberry Pi, is that they tend to lack performant open source drivers and may only be able to perform certain operations, like 3D rendering, with a proprietary driver.

The default Ubuntu environment, which is GNOME, requires a 3D-capable GPU and it will emulate 3D support using your CPU if your GPU can't provide it.  That's probably why the UI is so slow: your CPU is doing the work instead of your GPU.

You can try to see if there's a video driver available for Ubuntu by looking at the [wiki page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/RaspberryPi), or you can install a version of Ubuntu using a desktop environment such as MATE which is capable of working without 3D support.

Comment: Actually thanks a lot. I am now able to respond to you from my Raspberry Pi. :)